# How to make pagination with search result list in the list in spring boot thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new in spring boot with thymeleaf  a pagination with.So,i am struggling to make search result list pagination.Actually i make to paginate first all list from database and then search a data from the already display list in the thymeleaf and make pagination in the search data.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination Example  with spring boot thymeleaf :

*** Html thymeleaf pagination div *** :

```html
<!-- pagination liste client -->
   <nav aria-label="Page navigation example" class="navbar navbar toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <ul class="pagination nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item" th:classappend="${p}==${pageCourante}? 'active':''" th:each="p:${pages}" >
          <a class="page-link" th:classappend="${p}==${pageCourante}? 'active':''" th:text="${p}" th:href="@{listeClient(page=${p},motCle=${motCle})}">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

*** Controller *** :

```html
@Controller
public class ClientController {
 
 @Autowired
 private ClientRepository clientRepository;
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/listeClient", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String listeClient(Model model,
   @RequestParam(name="page", defaultValue="0")int p,
   @RequestParam(name="motCle", defaultValue="")String mc) {
  
  Page<Client> pageClients = clientRepository.chercherClients("%"+mc+"%", PageRequest.of(p, 5));
  
  int pagesCount = pageClients.getTotalPages();
  int[] pages = new int[pagesCount];
  for(int i=0; i<pagesCount; i++) pages[i] = i;
    
  model.addAttribute("pages", pages);
  model.addAttribute("pageCourante", p);
  model.addAttribute("motCle", mc);
  model.addAttribute("pageClients", pageClients);
  
  return "listeClient";
 }
```

*** Client Repository *** :

```html
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long> {
  @Query ("select c from Client c where c.nomClient like :x")
  public Page<Client> chercherClients(@Param("x")String mc, Pageable pageable);
}
```